# Custome scripts conflict with Magento 2 and requirejs!

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, jquery

I have custome jQuery scripts (revolution slider).
My steps:

1. Add custome js files to `app/design/frontend/Agestor/default/web/js`.
   [image: directory]
2. Create `requirejs-config.js` to `app/design/frontend/Vendor/default`.
   [image: requirejs-config]
   Or try like this:[image: 2 version]
3. Other 9 files connect in `jquery.themepunch.revolution.min` like this code:
   [image]
4. For call load js, add slider code to home page content:

   ```
   require(['jquery', 'jquery.themepunch.tools.min', 'jquery.themepunch.revolution.min'],function($){
       (function() {
            //code goes here
       })(jQuery);
   });
   ```

   Result: errors in console page, not work menu and checkout windows.
   [image: Errors]
   Please help, any tips...

Comment: When you say "Create requirejs-config.js to `app/design/frontend/Vendor/default`. " do you mean you have overitten the file inside vendor? If so this is very bad, you should be doing this in your theme not inside the vendor directory. This could be causing your problems. Also there is no need to declare the dependenices as their full name as you have already gave them an alias, e.g themepunchTools.

Comment: No, I add new requirejs-config.js to my theme. This is correct. I have tried various options, but due to lack of experience, I can not understand what the problem is.

Comment: I think the whole thing in requirejs and function new js. But I do not know how to fix it...

Comment: Hi, Did you find a resolution to this issue. We are using a custom theme which has similar issues.

Comment: Hello! Unfortunately no. Please let me know if you can find a solution.